# select statement with "Group by" on specific columns but displaying other columns along with group by columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get all data based on group by of only `encounter,medicationname`
column data..

```
select encounter,medicationname,count(*) as freq,labdate,result 
from Medications where (labdate between @admitdate and DATEDIFF(dd,24,@admitdate)) 
group by encounter,medicationname having count(*)>2
```

I have records like

```
encounter   medicationname  freq
8604261         ACC               3
```

Now based on this data ,I want to get

This is my desired output

```
encounter   medicationname  labtime     result
8604261       ACC              2015-05-22    18
8604261       ACC              2015-07-23    23
8604261       ACC              2015-09-09    27
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ? What is your desire output ?

Comment: i wanna get data if "freq" is greate than 2 then i need to get all columns data

Comment: don't you get answer based on posted answer ? I marked you just copied my answer in your question

Comment: encounter medicationname freq
V00860426118 ACCU-CHEK 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` as a window function, something like this:

```
;With Counted as (
   SELECT encounter,medicationname,labdate,result,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY encounter,medicationname) as cnt
   from Medications
   where (labdate between @admitdate
          and DATEDIFF(dd,24,@admitdate)) 
)
select encounter,medicationname,labdate,result
from Counted
where cnt > 2
```

I would note that I think `DATEDIFF`<sup>1</sup> is probably wrong also but since I don't have your data, inputs and an actual spec, I've left it as is for now.

---

<sup>1</sup>`DATEDIFF` returns an `int`, but you're using it in a comparison against a column which is apparently a `date`. `DATEADD` would be the more probably desired function here, but as I say, I don't have full information to go on.

Comment: yes , labdate is ofcourse date function ,u can suppose it as Dateadd..no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
select encounter,medicationname,count(*) as freq,labdate,result 
from Medications 
where (labdate between @admitdate and DATEDIFF(dd,24,@admitdate)) 
group by encounter,medicationname having count(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly what you need is this

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
select encounter,medicationname,count(*) as freq,labdate,result 
from Medications where (labdate between @admitdate and DATEDIFF(dd,24,@admitdate)) 
group by encounter,medicationname having count(*) > 2
)
select encounter,medicationname,labdate,result 
from Medications M
INNER JOIN CTE C
ON M.encounter = C.encounter
AND M.medicationname = C.medicationname
where (labdate between @admitdate and DATEDIFF(dd,24,@admitdate))
```

or better yet using `COUNT()OVER()`

```
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT encounter,medicationname,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY encounter,medicationname)as freq,labdate,result 
    FROM Medications
    WHERE (labdate between @admitdate and DATEDIFF(dd,24,@admitdate)) 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE freq > 2
```